# Python sqlite3 update deletes my row instead of updating the value

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to update a value x based on a specified row ID y in python using sqlite3. However, the issue I have is that instead of updating the value in the specified column, the script deletes the entire row/entry from the database.

Here is the function

```py
def closeIssue(self, issue_id, resolver_discord_id):
        # This function closes an open issue and assigns the resolver's ID
        self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM issues WHERE issue_id={}".format(issue_id))
        result = self.c.fetchone()
        if not result:
            print("No such record")
        else:
            self.c.execute("UPDATE issues SET issue_status = 'CLOSED' where issue_id = ?", (issue_id))
            self.conn.commit()

        self.__closeDatabase(False)
```

Just for further context, here are below some other parts of the module.

The database maker (and structure):

```py
def __buildDatabase(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.issue_db)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE issues (
                        issue_id integer,
                        issue_type text,
                        issue_type_verbose text,
                        author_discord integer,
                        issue_content text,
                        issue_status text,
                        issue_creation_timestamp text,
                        issue_closed_timestamp text,
                        resolver_staff_discord integer
                        )""")
        conn.commit()
        print("Database created")
```

What a typical entry looks like:

```
[{'issue_id': 1, 'issue_type': 'reports', 'issue_type_verbose': 'Report', 'author_discord': 124123123, 'issue_content': 'report one', 'issue_status': 'OPEN', 'issue_creation_timestamp': '14:29:33 - 20/02/2020', 'issue_closed_timestamp': 'NONE', 'resolver_staff_discord': 'NONE'}, {'issue_id': 2, 'issue_type': 'reports', 'issue_type_verbose': 'Report', 'author_discord': 41312, 'issue_content': 'report two', 'issue_status': 'OPEN', 'issue_creation_timestamp': '14:29:42 - 20/02/2020', 'issue_closed_timestamp': 'NONE', 'resolver_staff_discord': 'NONE'}]
```

I hope you can help me with this, thank you in advance! I've been hitting my head on this issue for the last few hours and cannot seem to find a solution anywhere I look.

Comment: Shouldn't the second parameter to `execute` be a tuple? `(issue_id)`-> `(issue_id,)`

Comment: There's a SQL injection vulnerability in the first `SELECT` execute statement.

Comment: Not necessarily apparently. Just tried with editing that and same issue, deleting the entire row instead of editing just the one value

Comment: Yes thank you @AKX , I will correct those once I have an actual code that works

Comment: Beyond that, an UPDATE clause will not delete a row by itself. Are you sure there is no trigger or similar at play? How do you know the row is deleted?

Comment: @AKX I am extremely stupid. See my answer below

Comment: @FrenchGap Figured it might've been an issue with your select, that's why I asked how you know it's gone. Glad you got it solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I am stupid. Apologies in advance and I guess I deserve it for the last three hours. Turns out the issue was in the way I displayed my test output... it was filtered out for only open cases.
Jesus.
Alright so confirmed this code works as intended.